# how to send fullcalendar day click date to other component in Angular5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular5, fullcalendar

I am trying to send the date to dialog(for registering new event).

This is how I added in CalendarOptions,

```
 calendarOptions = {
        header:
          {
            left: 'prev,next,today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
          },

        dayClick: (function (date, jsEvent, view) {
          let events$: Observable<Event[]> = this.store.select(fromAgenda.getAllEvents);
          this.onDayClicked.emit(events$);
        })
}
```

& my other Component has mentioned when I clicked on any day on calendar, It will open dailog for event registration as shown below,

```
 onDayClicked(event) {  
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EventNewComponent, {
    width: '750px'
  });

  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {    
   this.store.dispatch(new eventsActions.LoadAll());    
  });
  }
```

& It is opening dialog as below,

how to get clicked date as a start date on a dialog?
[EventNewComponent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgGBz.png)

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview 
"Sharing data with the Dialog component."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer.

```
 dayClick: (function (date, jsEvent, view) {
        let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EventNewComponent, {
          width: '750px',        
          data: {
            dataKey: date._d
          }
        });      
   })
```

& you can access it in other component by using constructor like below,

```
constructor( @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }
```

if your date is optional,

```
constructor( @Optional() @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }
```